# Output a SSJS variable with Ampscript for loop

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have a for loop in SSJS and I am trying to output it outside this scope using AMPSCRIPT. I know there is a way to output the value of a SSJS variable into AMPSCRIPT. My question is, how can output all the values of the for loop into AMPSCRIPT?

SSJS Loop:

Setting variables to be use outside of SSJS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{ 
    Platform.Variable.SetValue("client_id"+i, rows[i]['Count']);
}
```

AMPSCRIPT Output:
I wanna avoid doing the code below: I am wondering if can do something like:

@client_id[i] instead of my current static solution:

```
var s1 = [
    %%=v(@client_id0)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id1)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id2)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id3)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id4)=%%,
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appears as though you are trying to use the server side to populate the front end javascript using this code:

```
var s1 = [
    %%=v(@client_id0)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id1)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id2)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id3)=%%,
    %%=v(@client_id4)=%%,
];
```

In order to do that dynamically, you couldn't use AMPscript, as it doesn't allow for dynamic variables or arrays in this way (at least not one that I have found).

You can out put what you need however with SSJS

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var output = "var s1 = ["
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{ 
    output += i + ',';
}
output += "]";

Write(output);
</script>
```

This would accomplish the same as what you are currently doing, without the need for AMPscript.  Hope this helps!